Is it fair use to sell a photograph featuring dozens of graffiti tags in an expansive street scene?
I took a wide angle landscape, long exposure photograph of traffic streams that has several walls filled with graffiti, dozens of tags, is it fair to sell prints? The image features many things, businesses, trains, buildings, roads, traffic streams and also walls with various graffiti tags. Wouldn’t this be a new piece of art since it doesn’t feature any one piece of graffiti but many among other elements?
